# How can I instantiate a nil error using Golang's reflect?

Tags: go, reflection

I am writing a function using reflect.MakeFunc. That function can return an error. When it succeeds, I want it to return nil for its error-typed return value. How can I do that using reflect? Currently I have this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "errors"        
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    f := func() error {return nil}
    fn := reflect.MakeFunc(reflect.TypeOf(f), func(args []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
        return []reflect.Value{reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(errors.New("")))}
    }).Interface().(func() error)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v", fn())
}
```

I get `panic: reflect: function created by MakeFunc using closure returned wrong type: have **errors.errorString for error`. I also tried adding a `.Elem()` after `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(errors.New("")))`, but I got `panic: reflect: function created by MakeFunc using closure returned wrong type: have *errors.errorString for error`. I tried `.Elem().Elem()`, and I got a segmentation fault.

How can I get a reflect.Value representing a nil error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
var nilError = reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem())

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    f := func() error { return nil }
    fn := reflect.MakeFunc(reflect.TypeOf(f), func(args []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
        return []reflect.Value{nilError}
    }).Interface().(func() error)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v", fn())
}
```

Let's break this down. The first step is to get a `reflect.Type` for `error`:  `reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()`.  The simpler `reflect.TypeOf((error)(nil))` does not work because the concrete value of the argument is `nil`.  There's no type for `nil` and it's not the type we want anyway.  The workaround is to pass a pointer to `error` and then call `Elem()` on the type to get the `relfect.Type` for `error`.

The second step is to create a zero value for the type.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way - `reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(nil)`. Maybe there's a better one.