# how to append nil to dynamic type slice by reflect.Append

Tags: go, reflection, null, slice

Code below will raise a runtime error when append `reflect.Value` of `nil`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var list []interface{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(list)
    v = reflect.Append(v, reflect.ValueOf(1))   // [1]
    v = reflect.Append(v, reflect.ValueOf("1")) // [1, 1]
    v = reflect.Append(v, reflect.ValueOf(nil)) // runtime error
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

So

- why there is a runtime error?
- how can I use `reflect.Append` to add a `nil` to `interface{}` slice?

Comment: i think you should do a pointer then dereference it. Its what need to be done to create a nil error using golang reflection package. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092790/4466350

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang pass nil value as an interface through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937731/golang-pass-nil-value-as-an-interface-through-reflection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interface{}` is an interface type, and they are "tricky". They are wrappers around a concrete value and the concrete type, schematically a (value, type) pair.

So when you pass a concrete value to a function that expects an `interface{}` value, the concrete value will be wrapped in an `interface{}` value automatically, implicitly. If you pass a `nil` to such a function, the interface value itself will be `nil`. If you pass a `nil` pointer to it, such as `(*int)(nil)`, the interface value will not be `nil` but an interface value holding "(nil, *int)".

If you pass `nil` to `reflect.ValueOf()`, it results in a "zero" `reflect.Value` which represents no value at all. If you pass this to `reflect.Append()`, it will not have the type information, it will not know what you want to append to the slice.

It is possible to create a value that represents the `nil` interface value.

To do that, we may start from the type descriptor of a value of an interface pointer (pointers to interface *rarely* makes sense, but this is one of them). We navigate to the type descriptor of the pointed type, which is `interface{}`. We obtain a zero value of this type (using [`reflect.Zero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero)), which is `nil` (zero value of interface types is `nil`).

> Zero returns a Value representing the zero value for the specified type. The result is different from the zero value of the Value struct, which represents no value at all.

So this is how it looks like:

```
typeOfEmptyIface := reflect.TypeOf((*interface{})(nil)).Elem()
valueOfZeroEmptyIface := reflect.Zero(typeOfEmptyIface)
v = reflect.Append(v, valueOfZeroEmptyIface)
```

Or as a single line:

```
v = reflect.Append(v, reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((*interface{})(nil)).Elem()))
```

To check the results, let's use:

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", v)
```

And also let's type-assert back the slice, and add a `nil` value using the builtin `append()` function:

```
list = v.Interface().([]interface{})
list = append(list, nil)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", list)
```

Let's do an explicit, extra check if the elements are `nil` (compare them to `nil`). Although using `%#v` verb this is redundant, `%v` likes to print non-`nil` interfaces holding `nil` concrete values just as `nil` (the same as if the interface value itself would be `nil`).

```
fmt.Println(list[2] == nil, list[3] == nil)
```

Ouptut will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z78TdGyA9lr)):

```
[]interface {}{1, "1", interface {}(nil)}
[]interface {}{1, "1", interface {}(nil), interface {}(nil)}
true true
```

See related question: [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

Also: [The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)