# Put into Google Cloud Datastore fails for interface entity

Tags: pointers, go, google-cloud-platform, interface, google-cloud-datastore

I'm in the process of learning some basic concepts in Go and as such I'm experimenting with a data layer abstraction similar to what I would have done in other programming languages and I am running in the following error with my below code:

```
Failed to save task: datastore: invalid entity type
```

The code is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type DatastoreEntity interface {
    Kind() string
    Name() string
}

type Task struct {
    TaskId      string
    Description string
}

func (task *Task) Kind() string {
    return "tasks"
}

func (task *Task) Name() string {
    return task.TaskId
}

func main() {
    task := Task{
        TaskId:      uuid.New().String(),
        Description: "Buy milk",
    }
    SaveEntity(&task)
}

func SaveEntity(entity DatastoreEntity) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    projectId := "my-gcp-project"
    client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }

    entityKey := datastore.NameKey(entity.Kind(), entity.Name(), nil)

    if _, err := client.Put(ctx, entityKey, &entity); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to save task: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Saved %v: %v\n", entityKey, entity.Name())
}
```

Any help in explaining me why this doesn't work would be much appreciated.

My second question is that in the official [`datastore` Go package documentation](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore) it says the following:

```
// Create a datastore client. In a typical application, you would create
// a single client which is reused for every datastore operation.
dsClient, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-project")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}
```

What is the recommended pattern to instantiate a `dsClient` only once in an application?

Comment: The doc is pretty clear on `Client.Put()`: _"Put saves the entity src into the datastore with the given key. **src must be a struct pointer or implement PropertyLoadSaver**"_ You don't pass a struct pointer nor `PropertyLoadSaver`. You pass a pointer to interface type (which you should rarely if ever use).

Comment: Oh yes this was an oversight, so when I change `client.Put(ctx, entityKey, &entity)` to `client.Put(ctx, entityKey, entity)` it actually works. Thanks! However, when you say "You pass a pointer to interface type (which you should rarely if ever use)" would you mind to elaborate why I should never do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc is pretty clear on [`Client.Put()`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Client.Put):

> Put saves the entity src into the datastore with the given key. **src must be a struct pointer or implement PropertyLoadSaver.**

You don't pass a struct pointer nor `PropertyLoadSaver`. You pass a pointer to interface type (which you should rarely if ever use). In Go, interface is kind of like a "wrapper" type, it may wrap a concrete value and its type, where wrapped value may be a pointer too. So if a pointer is needed, the pointer is wrapped in the interface, so it's unneeded to use a pointer to the interface itself. In some cases it's still required or useful, but it's rare. Until you bump into a need for it, avoid it. An example may be when you need the reflect type descriptor of the interface type, see [how to append nil to dynamic type slice by reflect.Append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396510/how-to-append-nil-to-dynamic-type-slice-by-reflect-append/56396855#56396855).

Since you use `*Task` as your `entity` (which is a pointer to struct), simply use `entity` instead of `&entity`.

```
client.Put(ctx, entityKey, entity)
```

> What is the recommended pattern to instantiate a `dsClient` only once in an application?

One way to do it would be to use a package level ("global") variable where you store a `datastore.Client` created once. Wherever you need a `Client`, just refer to this variable.